# How to trigger function in Style object?

Tags: react-native

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

let globalIsTotal =false;
const component = ({ isTotal }) => {
  const { mainLabelStyle } = styles;

  globalIsTotal = isTotal;
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={mainLabelStyle}>Hello World</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  mainLabelStyle: {
    fontSize:28,
    flex: 1,
    fontWeight: () => {
      if(globalIsTotal===true){
        return 'bold';
      }
      return 'normal';
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to set the `fontWeight` of style depending on `globalIsTotal` value, but seems like the function is not being trigger. Wondering if this is the right way to handle such styling logic? This is a functional component which is reusable and props `isTotal` pass from caller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would achieve this like so:

Remove `fontWeight` from the style object

```
const styles = {
  mainLabelStyle: {
    fontSize:28,
    flex: 1
  }
}
```

And add it like so:

```
<Text style={[mainLabelStyle, { fontWeight: globalIsTotal ? 'bold' : 'normal'}]}>Hello World</Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use ternary expressions to trigger conditionals in objects, like:

```
mainLabelStyle: {
  fontSize:28,
  flex: 1,
  fontWeight: globalIsTotal ? 'bold' : 'normal'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my option about your issue :

```
let globalIsTotal =false;
const component = ({ isTotal }) => {
  const { mainLabelStyle } = styles;

  globalIsTotal = isTotal;
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={globalIsTotal==true ? [styles.mainLabelStyleBold] : [styles.mainLabelStyleNormal]}>Hello World</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  mainLabelStyleNormal: {
    fontSize:28,
    flex: 1,
    fontWeight: 'normal'
  }
  mainLabelStyleBold: {
    fontSize:28,
    flex: 1,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  }
}
```